# Keras Tensorflow - Exception while predicting from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I am using keras 2.0.8 with tensorflow 1.3.0 backend.

I am loading a model in the class init and then use it to predict multithreaded.

```python
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model


class CNN:
    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.cnn_model = load_model(model_path)
        self.session = K.get_session()
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    def query_cnn(self, data):
        X = self.preproccesing(data)
        with self.session.as_default():
            with self.graph.as_default():
                return self.cnn_model.predict(X)
```

I initialize the CNN once and the query_cnn method happens from multiple threads.

The exception i get in my log is:

```python
  File "/home/*/Similarity/CNN.py", line 43, in query_cnn
    return self.cnn_model.predict(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 913, in predict
    return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1713, in predict
    verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1269, in _predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2273, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: PruneForTargets: Some target nodes not found: group_deps
```

The code works fine most of the times, its probably some problem with the multithreading.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make sure you finish the graph creation before creating the other threads.

Calling `finalize()` on the graph may help you with that.

```python
def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.cnn_model = load_model(model_path)
        self.session = K.get_session()
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        self.graph.finalize()
```

**Update 1:** `finalize()` will make your graph read-only so it can be safely used in multiple threads. As a side effect, it will help you find unintentional behavior and sometimes memory leaks as it will throw an exception when you try to modify the graph.

Imagine that you have a thread that does for instance one hot encoding of your inputs. (bad example:)

```python
def preprocessing(self, data):
    one_hot_data = tf.one_hot(data, depth=self.num_classes)
    return self.session.run(one_hot_data)
```

If you print the amount of objects in the graph you will notice that it will increase over time

```python
# amount of nodes in tf graph
print(len(list(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node)))
```

But if you define the graph first that won't be the case (slightly better code):

```python
def preprocessing(self, data):
    # run pre-created operation with self.input as placeholder
    return self.session.run(self.one_hot_data, feed_dict={self.input: data})
```

**Update 2:** According to this [thread](https://github.com/jaara/AI-blog/issues/2) you need to call `model._make_predict_function()` on a keras model before doing multithreading.

> Keras builds the GPU function the first time you call predict(). That
>   way, if you never call predict, you save some time and resources.
>   However, the first time you call predict is slightly slower than every
>   other time.

The updated code:

```python
def __init__(self, model_path):
    self.cnn_model = load_model(model_path)
    self.cnn_model._make_predict_function() # have to initialize before threading
    self.session = K.get_session()
    self.graph = tf.get_default_graph() 
    self.graph.finalize() # make graph read-only
```

**Update 3:** I did a proof of concept of a warming up, because `_make_predict_function()` doesn't seems to work as expected.
First I created a dummy model:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.save("dummymodel")
```

Then in another script I loaded that model and made it run on multiple threads

```python
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model
import threading as t
import numpy as np

K.clear_session()

class CNN:
    def __init__(self, model_path):

        self.cnn_model = load_model(model_path)
        self.cnn_model.predict(np.array([[0,0]])) # warmup
        self.session = K.get_session()
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        self.graph.finalize() # finalize

    def preproccesing(self, data):
        # dummy
        return data

    def query_cnn(self, data):
        X = self.preproccesing(data)
        with self.session.as_default():
            with self.graph.as_default():
                prediction = self.cnn_model.predict(X)
        print(prediction)
        return prediction


cnn = CNN("dummymodel")

th = t.Thread(target=cnn.query_cnn, kwargs={"data": np.random.random((500, 2))})
th2 = t.Thread(target=cnn.query_cnn, kwargs={"data": np.random.random((500, 2))})
th3 = t.Thread(target=cnn.query_cnn, kwargs={"data": np.random.random((500, 2))})
th4 = t.Thread(target=cnn.query_cnn, kwargs={"data": np.random.random((500, 2))})
th5 = t.Thread(target=cnn.query_cnn, kwargs={"data": np.random.random((500, 2))})
th.start()
th2.start()
th3.start()
th4.start()
th5.start()

th2.join()
th.join()
th3.join()
th5.join()
th4.join()
```

Commenting the lines for the warmingup and finalize I was able to reproduce your first issue

Comment: Should i finalize after saving the graph variable?

Comment: The issue is that the graph creation [is not thread-safe](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures), so you need to finish the graph creation in one thread, and then start the others. `finalize()` will make the graph read-only

Comment: I uploaded it to production and i wait to see if it comes back. For now its good. I will give it a few days more.

Comment: I am now getting - File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2290, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.

Comment: That means you are modifying the graph or creating more operations after the `finalize()`,  it can be on `self.preproccesing(data)`,or somewhere else besides your main model

Comment: If you add operations to the graph unintentionally on those threads, that's a memory leak

Comment: I can see on the traceback that "Graph is finalized and cannot be modified." is called by the line `return self.cnn_model.predict(X)`. So this is not happening on the preprocessing stage, and there is nothing in the preprocessing that use tf. Maybe somehow keras is trying to change the graph?

Comment: You were right, keras is updating the graph, I updated my answer, you need to call `_make_predict_function()`.

Comment: Still getting the `Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.` error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: :(, the next thing that I would try is to warmup the model with dummy data in the `__init__()` function. Something like `self.cnn_model.predict(np.zeros(inputdim))`

Comment: I added a POC of the warming up, hope it helps

Comment: Looks like making a predict on the init is working! I will try it in production and see if it goes well.

Comment: That K.get_session() part helped me！It seems session contains the initialized variables of the model. using default session is necessary to use model from default graph. Thank you so much. This blocked me for nearly two day.

Comment: Getting Graph is finalized and cannot be modified. what tf version you tested on?